# RadAjax not firing on 1st click after client side event handler

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, radajaxmanager

I'm using RadAjaxManager to ajaxify some WebForms controls. The ajax works fine in all scenarios except one:

I have a LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSaveButton" 
                    Text="Save" 
                    OnClick="lnkSaveButton_Click"
                    OnClientClick="if ( ! validateValidation()) return false;"
                    runat="server" />
```

The `validateValidation` function fires some client side page validation on my form controls, which returns `false` to block the form from submitting if the Page is invalid.

In the case that the Page is invalid, all of the controls targeted by `RadAjaxManager` fail to fire their ajax request on the first click (only) after the validation completes.

Any subsequent click on the ajaxified control fires the request correctly. It's also worth noting that *all* of the Ajaxified controls work correctly after *one* ajaxified control has been clicked once. Clicking on any non-ajaxified control (not targeted by RadAjaxManager) has no impact.

It's also worth noting that if I replace `RadAjaxManager` with simple `RadAjaxPanel`s I get the exact same result as described above.

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- ensure you are not adding AjaxSettings that encompass RadAjaxPanel controls
- make sure no script errors are thrown, especially by the validation
- try calling the [ajaxRequsetWithTarget](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ajaxmanager/client-side-programming/overview#ajaxrequestwithtargeteventtarget-eventargument) in the client-side handler if validation is successful, something like:

  ```
      <telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="RadCodeBlock1">
          <script>
              function validateValidation() {
                  var validatinPassed = true;
                  $find("<%=RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID%>").ajaxRequestWithTarget('<%= lnkSaveButton.UniqueID %>', '');
                  return false;
              }
          </script>
      </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSaveButton"
                      Text="Save"
                      OnClick="lnkSaveButton_Click"
                      OnClientClick="if (! validateValidation())
                          return false;"
                      runat="server" />
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="text" runat="server" />
      <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
          <AjaxSettings>
              <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="lnkSaveButton">
                  <UpdatedControls>
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lnkSaveButton" />
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Label1" />
                  </UpdatedControls>
              </telerik:AjaxSetting>
          </AjaxSettings>
      </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
  ```

  and a sample handler for testing

  ```
  protected void lnkSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I think I have most of this covered but I will try the `ajaxRequestWithTarget` function soon and let you know how it goes.